# Print value of dictionary item in list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
list  = [1,2,"three",{"number":4}]

for item in list:
        if type(item) is dict:
            print([val for val in item.values()][0])
        else:
            print(item)
```

In the example above, provided I would **not** know that the key of the dictionary item is named `number`, is there an easier (or more elegant) way to print just the value of the item?

Comment: Hmm.. so you don't want the `else` case?

Comment: I don't understand the question. For the item in question, `print(item)` prints `{'number': 4}`. But I want it to print just `4`.

Comment: You print 1, 2, "three" in the `else`. If you need to print only value of `"number"` key, remove `else: print(item)`. If not, I don't understand the original question.

Comment: Just run the code. It does what I want. BUT I would like to know if I can get the number `4` easier than with the `[val for val in item.values()][0]`-construct. Like in Powershell I would just write`$item.value` and I would get the `4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguably more elegant way to extract the first value from a dict would be to write:

```
print(next(iter(item.values())))
```

Comment: From the OP's own code of `[val for val in item.values()][0]`, all he wants from a dict is the very first value, regardless of the key.

Comment: You are right. So there is not equivalent to `$item.value`? I guess I was looking for something like `value(item)` :-). I just started learning Python....

Comment: @Rob Nope there is not. Unless you write such a function yourself.